# "We operate with some stock images of the addict." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> "We *operate* with some *stock* images of the addict."

•[Larger context](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Df55QO2isoKM&ved=0ahUKEwiC3PCqpKLdAhWSrFMKHdrfB_wQo7QBCCAwAA&usg=AOvVaw0iVevP5_rkwciygSTYmBbf)(it's in first seconds)

I've read all of the definitions of these two words "[operate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operate)" & "[stock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stock)" & I think they do not make any sense here in this context. What does stock images mean?

Therefore, I couldn’t think of a suitable answer to this question:

What does this sentence totally mean?

I think, (it's just a guess) that it means:

> We got used to it, to this particular idea about the addict by these very negative advertisements against addicts.

Comment: Your answer would be  improved by searching for stock images, not operate and stock. Stock  images is the proper parse.

Comment: @Lambie Yes! I searched for it 8 hours ago, couldn't find anything about "stock images" & "operate with". –

Comment: my bad, I meant "stock photos".

Answer (score 4):

It is not a literal meaning of the term **stock images** that is being invoked there, but a figurative one, namely "stereotypical ideas or notions". We have in mind certain stereotypes.

To operate with stereotypical notions is to approach a situation not with an open mind but with a mind that is likely to filter the reality through the lens of these notions, to ignore what goes contrary to the preconceptions and to notice only the things that reinforce them.